# Transforming attributes to elements with matching name in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to create an XSLT which tranforms an attribute in the source xml to a new element in the target xml with the element name assigned the "Name" value of the attribute in the source xml.

Eg:

Source:

```
<ProductType>Fridge</ProductType>
    <Features>
      <Feature Name="ValveID">somename</Feature>
      <Feature Name="KeyIdentifier">someID</Feature>
```

Result:

```
<Fridge>
    <Feature>somename</Feature>
    <Feature>someID</Feature>
```

Expected Result:

```
  <Fridge>
        <ValueID>somename</ValueID>
        <KeyIdentifier>someID</KeyIdentifier>
```

My XSLT looks like this for now:

```
1 <Fridge>
2       <xsl:for-each select="$var6_ProductData/Features/Feature">
3            <xsl:variable name="var8_Feature" select="."/>
4            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
5                 <xsl:value-of select="string($var8_Feature)"/>
6            </xsl:element>
7       </xsl:for-each>
8 </Fridge>
```

I need to change line 4 but not sure how. Any ideas??

---

D

Answer (score 4):

Generic solution (and more idiomatic, too):

```
<xsl:template match="ProductType">
  <xsl:element name="{text()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Features/Feature" />
  </xsl:elemment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Features/Feature">
  <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
  </xsl:elemment>
</xsl:template>
```

`<ProductType>` elements are transformed into a new element with a dynamic name, same goes for `<Feature>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

I would try

```
<xsl:element name="{@Name}">
```

as `name()` gives you the name of the XML element "Feature" (selected by the `xsl:for-each`), not the content of the current node's `Name=` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
1 <Fridge>
2       <xsl:for-each select="$var6_ProductData/Features/Feature">
3            <xsl:variable name="var8_Feature" select="."/>
3            <xsl:variable name="var9_Feature" select="@Name"/>
4            <xsl:element name="{$var9_Feature}">
5                 <xsl:value-of select="string($var8_Feature)"/>
6            </xsl:element>
7       </xsl:for-each>
8 </Fridge>
```

Comment: Dipesh, I would go with Tomalak's implementation as it is generic and provides more flexibility for enhancements